# Convert Double to NSDate time, for querying on Parse

Tags: swift, double, nsdate

I have two Doubles, and need to query for NSDate's with a timeinterval that matches the two doubles.. How can I convert a Double to a NSDate with time matching my Double? :) If it's possible at all..

Edit: Sorry, I was in a bit of a hurry - my apologies! The Doubles I have, represent a time of the day, like 8.00 or 17.00 .. So I need to convert that Double, to a time in an NSDate, If that makes sense :)

Comment: You need to provide more detail. Do you know what the numbers represent? Have you looked at the documentation for `NSDate` (or `Date`)?

Comment: @rmaddy - thanks for your reply! I've updated my question, maybe it makes more sense now :) But I'll have a look at the documentation - don't know why I didn't think of that..

Answer (score 0):

Simple use `timeIntervalSince1970` and pass double value as parameter.

```
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: doubleValue)
```

Comment: This assumes the values the OP have represent time intervals since January 1, 1970.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't too clear. I need the NSDate for a current date, with a time matching a Double like 8.00 (in the morning), or 16.00 in the afternoon :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with a bit of hints from your answers. Here's what I ended up with and it works perfectly:

```
let date = NSDate()
let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
let newDate = cal.startOfDayForDate(date)

let secondsSince1970ToYesterdayAt23 = newDate.timeIntervalSince1970
let secondsInOneHour = 3600.0

let secondsSince1970FromMidnight = secondsSince1970ToYesterdayAt23 + secondsInOneHour

let secondsFromMidnightToStartTime = (secondsInOneHour * (slider?.lowerValue)!) + secondsSince1970FromMidnight
let dateWithStartTime = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: secondsFromMidnightToStartTime)

let secondsFromMidnightToEndTime = (secondsInOneHour * (slider?.upperValue)!) + secondsSince1970FromMidnight
let dateWithEndTime = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: secondsFromMidnightToEndTime)

print("Start \(dateWithStartTime)") // Returning 2017-03-18 08:00:00 +0000
print("End: \(dateWithEndTime)") // Returning 2017-03-18 17:00:00 +0000
```